# save a field from one table to a PHP variable and used in another query

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

I want to create an API to submit data to database. The main function is to update the inventory. When I insert or update rows in minibar(table 1), i need to update the movement in minibar_movements(table 2). Here are the two tables:

```
table 1 minibar
___________________________________________________________
id    location_id    room_id    menu_item    last_quantity
___________________________________________________________
250   1111           310        Sprite       4

table 2 minibar_movements
________________________________________________
id     minibar_id     location_id     qty_added
________________________________________________
1      250            1111            2
```

the API will create a record in table 1 only if a record doesn't already exist. If it exist, just update it. Meanwhile, a record will also be created or updated in table 2. My issue is that when I execute a query in table 1 I need to save the id from table 1 and used in table 2 as minibar_id. Only a query executed in table 1 could lead a update in table 2. Here is part of my code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM minibar";
$query2 = "UPDATE minibar SET 
          last_quantity='$last_quantity'
          WHERE location_id='$location_id' AND room_id='$location_id' AND menu_item='$menu_item'";
$query3 = "INSERT INTO minibar 
          (location_id,room_id,menu_item,last_quantity)
          VALUES('$location_id', '$room_id','$menu_item','$last_quantity')";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
if( $rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        if($location_id==$row['location_id'] && $room_id==$row['location_id'] && $menu_item==$row['menu_item']) {
            // just update
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
            //$minibar_id = mysql_result(result2,0,'minibar.id');
        }
        else {
            // insert new record
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
           // $minibar_id = mysql_result(result2,0,'minibar.id');
        }
    }
}
else {
    $result4 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
   // $minibar_id = mysql_result(result2,0,'minibar.id');
}
```

Because the minivar_id in table 2 is the same as id in table 1. Every time an query is executed in table 1 need to update a movement in table with the field minibar_id == id. So how could I save the value in PHP and used in other queries related to table 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use this in your `while` loop

```
$query2 = $query2." AND minibar_id="$row['minibar_id']);
```

Or you could use `sprintf()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Your `query` would look like this

```
$query2 = "UPDATE minibar
           SET last_quantity='$last_quantity'
           WHERE location_id='$location_id' 
           AND room_id='$location_id' 
           AND menu_item='$menu_item' 
           AND minibar_id = '%s' ";
```

in your while loop use

```
$query2 = sprintf($query2, $row['minibar_id']);
```